# Obtener registro con dos coincidencia en la misma tabla de relaciones

Tags: php, mysql

Estimados necesito obtener un registro que tenga dos relaciones, les explico:

Tengo las tablas:

> CONTENIDO: id - titulo - descripcion
>
> CATEGORIA: id - titulo
>
> CONTENIDOS_X_CATEGORIAS: idContenido - idCategoria

Siempre que quiere obtener un "contenido" que esta en una categoria lo hago asi (consulta mysql desde php):

```
SELECT contenidos.*
FROM contenidos 
INNER JOIN contenido_x_categorias 
ON contenido_x_categorias.idContenido = contenidos.id
WHERE contenido_x_categorias.idCategoria = $idCategoria
```

Donde `$idCategoria`  es la categoria de filtro.

**La pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo hacer para buscar un contenido que este en dos categorias al mismo tiempo?**

Le agregue un `AND` al `WHERE` y obviamente no me trajo ningun resultado.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Te interesa obtener solo el `idCategoria`? ¿El `ID` de la segunda categoría, en que variable estaría? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el resultado esperado.

Comment: Enzo ¿podrías decir qué columnas exactamente necesitas en tus resultados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los `join`s se utilizan cuando quieres obtener resultados de varias tablas y trabajar con los datos como si fuse una única tabla.

En este caso quieres obtener un contenido (que esté en dos categorías), por lo que yo haría:

```
SELECT *
FROM contenidos
WHERE
  contenidos.id IN (
    SELECT idContenido
    FROM contenido_x_categorias
    WHERE contenido_x_categorias.idCategoria = $idCategoria1 
  )
  AND
  contenidos.id IN (
    SELECT idContenido
    FROM contenido_x_categorias
    WHERE contenido_x_categorias.idCategoria = $idCategoria2 
  )
```

Es posible que esta sentencia SQL se pueda optimizar. Si no tienes muchos cambios en las tablas, puedes cachear en PHP los listados de ID de producto por categoría, y así te evitas esas dos consultas extra.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero yo necesito que el contenido, este en dos relaciones de la tabla de relaciones. Seria asi???

SELECT *
FROM contenidos
WHERE contenidos.id IN (
  SELECT idContenido
  FROM contenido_x_categorias
  WHERE contenido_x_categorias.idCategoria = $idCategoria  AND contenido_x_categorias.idCategoria = $idCategoria2
)

Comment: No, eso te generaría una lista de ids vacía porque ninguna fila tiene dos valores distintos de `idCategoria`. Edito la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, justo esto es lo que buscaba!

Answer (score 0):

Enzo, si en tu resultado la información que te interesa mostrar está en la tabla `contenido`, o simplemente saber cuáles tienen dos ocurrencias, puedes lograr lo que buscas con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT  
    con.contenido_id, con.contenido_titulo
FROM contenido_20180116 con 
INNER JOIN contenido_categoria_20180116 cc1 ON con.contenido_id=cc1.contenido_id
INNER JOIN categoria_20180116 cat ON cc1.categoria_id=cat.categoria_id
GROUP BY (con.contenido_id)
HAVING COUNT(con.contenido_id)=2
ORDER BY con.contenido_id;
```

- Haces un solo `JOIN` entre `contenido` y `contenido_categoria`
- Agrupas por `contenido_id`
- Usas `HAVING` para contar los registros que tienen dos coincidencias. Modificando el valor `=2` puedes aplicar otros filtros, admitiendo también evaluaciones del tipo *mayor o igual a*, *menor o igual a*, etc.
- Podrías agregar un filtro `WHERE` si así lo necesitaras.

---

### Prueba de concepto

**[<kbd>VER DEMO EN REXTESTER</kbd>](http://rextester.com/LYCO83678)**

#### Código

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contenido_20180116 
(
    contenido_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    contenido_titulo VARCHAR(70),
    contenido_descripcion VARCHAR(70)

)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoria_20180116 
(
    categoria_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    categoria_titulo VARCHAR(70)

)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contenido_categoria_20180116 (
    contenido_id INT, 
    categoria_id INT, 
    UNIQUE KEY (contenido_id, categoria_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (contenido_id) REFERENCES contenido_20180116(contenido_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (categoria_id) REFERENCES categoria_20180116(categoria_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;


INSERT INTO contenido_20180116 (contenido_titulo, contenido_descripcion)
    VALUES 
    ('Titulo1', 'Descripción1'),
    ('Titulo2', 'Descripción2'),
    ('Titulo3', 'Descripción3'),
    ('Titulo4', 'Descripción4'),
    ('Titulo5', 'Descripción5')
;

INSERT INTO categoria_20180116 (categoria_titulo)
    VALUES 
    ('Cat-Titulo1'),
    ('Cat-Titulo2'),
    ('Cat-Titulo3')
;

INSERT INTO contenido_categoria_20180116 (contenido_id,categoria_id)
    VALUES 
    (1,1),
    (1,3),
    (2,1),
    (2,2),
    (3,1),
    (4,2),
    (5,1)

;

SELECT  
    con.contenido_id, con.contenido_titulo
FROM contenido_20180116 con 
INNER JOIN contenido_categoria_20180116 cc1 ON con.contenido_id=cc1.contenido_id
INNER JOIN categoria_20180116 cat ON cc1.categoria_id=cat.categoria_id
GROUP BY (con.contenido_id)
HAVING COUNT(con.contenido_id)=2
ORDER BY con.contenido_id;
```

#### Resultado

```
contenido_id    contenido_titulo
1               Titulo1
2               Titulo2
```

Comment: Gracias, me guardo tu respuesta porque puede servirme en el futuro.